# Hadoop Project - Find customers with the max consumption in a certain day

Tags: java, database, hadoop, mapreduce

I am creating a project in Hadoop. I don't know much about Hadoop and the MapReducing process, so here is my question: I have a big dataset with three columns; Customer's id, Timestamp (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) and consumption. I want to find the customers, with the max consumption in a certain day, that I will choose.

Here is my code:

**My Driver**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class alicanteDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        long t_start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long t_end;

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();//JobConf(WordCountDriver.class);//
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "WorCount");
        job.setJarByClass(alicanteDriver.class);
        //job.setMapperClass(alicanteMapper.class);
        job.setMapperClass(alicanteMapperC.class);        

        //job.setCombinerClass(alicanteCombiner.class);

        job.setPartitionerClass(alicantePartitioner.class);
        //job.setPartitionerClass(alicantePartitionerC.class);

        job.setNumReduceTasks(8);
        job.setReducerClass(alicanteReducer.class);
        //job.setReducerClass(alicanteReducerC.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/alicante_1y.txt"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/alicante_output"));
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
        t_end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println((t_end-t_start)/1000);
    }
 }
```

**My Mapper**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class alicanteMapperC extends
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    String Customer = new String();
    SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date t = new Date();
    Date d2 = new Date();
    IntWritable Consumption = new IntWritable();
    int counter = 0;

    // temp variables
    int max = 0;
    String cust = new String();

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        try {
            d2 = ft.parse("2013-07-01 01:00:00");
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // find max
        if (counter > 0) {
            String line = value.toString();
            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");

            while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
                Customer = itr.nextToken();
                Consumption.set(Integer.parseInt(itr.nextToken()));
                try {
                    t = ft.parse(itr.nextToken());
                    if (t.compareTo(d2) == 0) {
                        max = Math.max(max, Consumption.get());
                    }
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

**My Reducer**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;



public class alicanteReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {   
    int Consumption;
    String Customer;
    int max;
    IntWritable sum_consumption = new IntWritable();
    IntWritable ca = new IntWritable();

      public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
          throws IOException, InterruptedException {

          //int sum = 0;      
          for (IntWritable val:values){ 
              max = val.get();
              Consumption = val.get();
              Customer = val.toString();
              if(Consumption == max){
                  context.write(new Text(Customer), ca);
              }
              //sum += Consumption;
          }
          //sum_consumption.set(sum);
          //context.write(new Text(Integer.toString(max)), sum_consumption); 
      }
    }
```

As you can see, I am able to find the max consumption in a certain day. What I am unable to do, is to associate the customers with this max consumption in this certain day and write their IDs in an output file.

I tried running a *second while* in the mapper class, using the max in order to find the customers, but it was taking too long.

Any ideas on how the structure of the program should be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the mapper does not seem to produce any output records, as you don't use `context.write()`

Comment: @vefthym I know. I need to find first the customers with the max consumption and then write them in the output file.

Comment: but then no input is given to the reducer... in any case, why don't you first filter out all the wrong dates, then emit the *local* max of each mapper in the `close()` method of the mapper and find the global max in the reducer?

Comment: @vefthym Can I, somehow, pass the global max that I find in the mapper class (as seen in the code) to the reduce class, so as to find there the customers?

Comment: You cannot find the global max in the mapper, unless you are running MapReduce in a single-node cluster (or your laptop). Otherwise, the max that you find in the map phase is local for each mapper.

Comment: @vefthym Please forgive me for my ignorance, but I am new in this whole process. I am running cloudera in a virtual machine, with hadoop enabled. I am running the project in my PC, so I guess I use only one single-node cluster?

Comment: Yes, it should work on your laptop, but it doesn't make much sense to run it there. MapReduce is meant to run programs in parallel (in a cluster). Even if it works in your laptop, your program should not be designed to run in a single machine only. Otherwise, you don't need MapReduce.

Comment: @vefthym Keeping aside the one cluster issue, do you think I should find the global max of the input file (a txt with many records in it) on the mapper's class and then pass it to the reducer's class , in order to find there the customers I want? Do you suggest sth else?